# zend framework paginator does not work?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

I use ZendFramework Paginator and I have some code like this:

```
    $defaultCount=1000;
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select = $db->select();

    $select->from(array('u' => 'core_users'));
    $select->join(array('ur' => 'core_users_roles'), 'u.uid = ur.uid');
    $select->join(array('r' => 'core_roles'), 'r.rid = ur.rid');

    $adapter=new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);

    $adapter->setRowCount($db->select()->from('core_users',array(Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect::ROW_COUNT_COLUMN =>'uid')));

    $paginator= new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($defaultCount);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
```

but ,i can not get all of my data from DbSelect Adapter.when i remove  $defaultCount , it always give me  20 total data (default ,I guess). should i use single table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$db->select()->from('core_users',array(Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect::ROW_COUNT_COLUMN =>'uid'))`

give me wrong number. I use hard code ,works on me.